# Why phonegap application always shows own default page after override index.html

Tags: android, html, cordova

Hi I have made a hello world type of application in PhoneGap. I have index.html in `www` directory but it is displaying something default home page of phonegap. Please see attached screenshot that it is displaying always.

index.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
        <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
        <!-- WARNING: for iOS 7, remove the width=device-width and height=device-height attributes. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-4323 -->
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
        <title>Hello World</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            app.initialize();
        </script>

        <form>
            Select your favourite color: <input type="color" name="favcolor">
            <br/>
            <input type="button" value="SUBMIT" />
        </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

But when I run the app in android phone it always display this. I have done 3-4 rebuild complete project but still same.

I am not sure what is going wrong or missing.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Try to manually change the www folder contents before building in the platforms you have added and then take the build and see if it works.

Comment: @ashfaq.p Yes I changed & uploaded code as well in the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are making changes to www folder present inside the platforms added.
Try to make changes in the www folder which is present in the root folder of your project and then take a build and it will definitely work.
Check This: [image]

Comment: See this https://www.dropbox.com/s/f00yh7up7uygbpb/8.png?dl=0 I edited in this index.html

Comment: But your code is working fine for me in the emmulator as well as my android device. can you upload your complete demo folder to dropbox.

Comment: I see there is platform folder also there then android then platform_www .. do i have to add there ?

Comment: No do not change anything inside platform. It automatically gets updated when you take a build with all the changes you have made in the root www folder.