# Phonegap compiled show default index.html?

Tags: cordova

I'm getting crazy...in browser and PhoneGap Developer I see the index.html I've done, then I use PhoneGap Build to compile, download the .ipa file, add it in iTunes, open the app in the iPhone and shows me the default index.html....

I've tried to use GapDebug and installed in the iPhone and still the same, already created new apps to check and happens the same all the time.

Anyone had this issue? I found [Why phonegap application always shows own default page after override index.html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26820651/why-phonegap-application-always-shows-own-default-page-after-override-index-html) but no solution :(

Answer (score 0):

First make sure you have made your changes on index.html file inside the www directory of your root folder of project, not inside the platform directory.

After that, check your `config.xml` file, inorder to start your app from index.html your `content` element should be like this :

```
<content src="index.html" />
```